# bootstrap control label and input on different rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my textarea appear one row below the control-label. How do I make this happen? Thanks!

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="textAreaField">Question here:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea id="textAreaField" class="span12" rows="3">Nil.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [**Horizontal form**](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms) layout. Just remove the classes.

```
<form>
    <label for="textAreaField">Question here:</label>
    <textarea id="textAreaField" class="span12" rows="3">Nil.</textarea>
</form>
```